# Aurelia - Overriding css binding inside custom element

Tags: css, aurelia, custom-element

What I want to achieve is to have custom element and bind css directly to this element from parent but also from within the custom element.

parent:

```
<div>
   <custom-element css="height: ${heightProperty}"></custom-element>
</div>
```

custom element:

```
<template css="width: ${widthProperty}">
</template>
```

But width and height properties will not be binded at the same time. Only the one which was binded (changed) last will take effect. But merging seems to work when setting class property. So is this bug or intended?

Comment: Would you mind posting this to the templating-binding repo as a bug so we can discuss if this is a bug or intended behavior? Thanks :-)

Comment: @AshleyGrant In all honesty I would expect the outermost binding (on a single property) to simply override the innermost. I'd argue that the fact that this works with the `class` property is a consequence of `classList` being an array (which uses collection observer) as opposed to `style` (which is an object), but still an unintentional one, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the way to go/ proper way of doing this, but what happens when you add a bindable CSS property to your custom element?

Like this:

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';
export class customElement {
  @bindable()
  css = '';
}
```

and then in your HTML

```
<template css="width: ${widthProperty} ${css}">
</template>
```

Comment: This works. But still I consider this a workaround.

Edit: but <template css="width: ${widthProperty} ${css}"> should be <template css="width: ${widthProperty}; ${css}"> with semicolon

Comment: I don't consider this a workaround at all. What you are trying to do is equivalent to `<custom-element css="height: ${heightProperty} css="width: ${widthProperty}">`. @Erik has it right.